# Question on Bernoulli Trials and Binomial Distributions

Tags: distributions

What distribution can I use to describe the trial number of the first success given a sequence of Bernoulli trials?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a Geometric Distribution

Assume the probability of success is $p$ (fixed) then the probability of a success on the k-th trial is:

\begin{equation}
Pr(X=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p, \text{  where }k=1,2,..
\end{equation}

[Geometric_distribution - wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)